# How could I download the images in Selenium when the BytesIO error occur?

Tags: python, image, selenium

I am trying to get the images from one webpage, but I am not being able to solve it. I am getting an error message saying:

> `cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000270FA2A27C0>`

I read other posts but I was not able to find a solution.

The webpage I am using has [this formatting](https://veranstaltungen.bayern.by/eichstaett/bayerische-bierwoche-im-landkreis-eichstaett-eecdc1a24f2d6475a6203cc7ef98c1672.html)

So the print of `image2` recognizes the URL of the `.jpg` properly, but it is not possible through the other work, as it says:

> `cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000270FA2A27C0>`

What am I doing wrong?

In the following, I have written:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image # pip install Pillow
import io
from selenium import webdriver # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

opts = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe', options=opts) 

image2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//figure[@class="gallery__image"]/img').get_attribute('src')
print (image2)

#IMAGE
url = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//figcaption/a')
url = url.get_attribute('href')
# obtengo el URl de la imagen del anuncio
# con requests, hago el requerimiento a la URL de la imagen

image_content = requests.get(url).content
image_file = io.BytesIO(image_content)
image = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGB')
file_path = 'D:\imagenescode\Alemania\Bayern/' + str(i).replace('.png','').replace('/','').replace('?','').replace(':','') + '.jpg'  # nombre a guardar de la imagen
      with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
          image.save(f, "JPEG", quality=85)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `image2` link is not sanitized properly. The looks like something this `https://www.rce-event.de/modules/output/thumbnailer.php?q=75&w=740&h=500&zc=C&src=httpss%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturpark-altmuehltal.de%2Fdata%2Fthumbs%2Fimg%2F9470639_wp_20170421_012.jpg`

This `/modules/output/thumbnailer.php` app takes some parameters and an image source URL `(httpss%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturpark-altmuehltal.de%2Fdata%2Fthumbs%2Fimg%2F9470639_wp_20170421_012.jpg)` to resize the image and show them on that site. so you can say that `https://www.rce-event.de/modules/output/thumbnailer.php?q=75&w=740&h=500&zc=C&src=httpss%3A%2F%2Fwww.naturpark-altmuehltal.de%2Fdata%2Fthumbs%2Fimg%2F9470639_wp_20170421_012.jpg` is not the actual URL of the image/ the actual URL of the image is `www.naturpark-altmuehltal.de/data/thumbs/img/9470639_wp_20170421_012.jpg`.

So to get the actual image you need to extract the actual image URL from the first non sanitized URL.

And this error `cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x00000270FA2A27C0>` occurs for that mistake I think. That first URL does not return any data. Though I am not familiar with the io library I think `io.BytesIO()` function gets the binary data of the image and saves it. The same can be done with this

```
file = open("image_name.jpg", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
```

In the first-line `"wb"` stands for write binary. This means the binary data of the image file will be written in an `image_name.jpg` file.

Here is the full source code

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver # pip install selenium

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/google/chrome/chromedriver')

link = 'https://veranstaltungen.bayern.by/eichstaett/bayerische-bierwoche-im-landkreis-eichstaett-eecdc1a24f2d6475a6203cc7ef98c1672.html'

driver.get(link)

image2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//figure[@class="gallery__image"]/img').get_attribute('src')

img_link = image2.replace('%2F', '/')

index = img_link.find('www.naturpark-altmuehltal.de')
link = img_link[index:]

print(link)
response = requests.get(f'https://{link}')

file = open("Image_name.jpg", "wb")
file.write(response.content)
file.close()
driver.quit()
```